# Converting SVG using svg2png (phantomjs) failing to load cloundinary images on live server

Tags: svg, phantomjs, cloudinary

I'm using the lastest version of [svg2png](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png) to covert svgs like the one below into png's

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/boxxer/uploads/items/57c46a04f1dc422b002ff291.svg

Locally this works without any issues, but when I deploy my app to Flynn it seems to not be rendering the images referenced in the defs and the result look like the image below

https://res.cloudinary.com/dot-to-dot-design/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_600/boxxer_s3/uploads/items/57c46a04f1dc422b002ff291_1472543810612.png

If I replace the cloudinary images with ones hosted on the server the png renders ok.

Also the current version of my site that's running on a different server and admittedly an older version of svg2png also works fine.

The problem I'm having is knowing exactly what's causing the issue as there are several new things.

Flynn server hosting, where the maintainers have advised that there shouldn't be anything blocking the images from loading.

svg2png can't help because I can't replicate it locally.

Cloudinary have also advised that there should be any reason for the images not to load.

Comment: Did you try opening the image above before uploading to Cloudinary? Did it display properly?
Cloudinary can help converting the SVG to PNG on their side, for example: http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/f_png/https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/boxxer/uploads/items/57c46a04f1dc422b002ff291.svg

Comment: Unfortunately their conversion is broken at least on the files I'm trying to convert and they've been promising a fix for 2 or 3 weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but I manage to resolve my isssue by removing the https protocol so the reference to my images looks like

//res.cloudinary.com/dot-to-dot-design/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_600/boxxer_s3/uploads/items/57c46a04f1dc422b002ff291_1472543810612.png